# Change Row Color of Table When TD Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**Background**

I am dynamically creating a table with php. Inside one of the `<td>` I am adding a `js function`. When a user clicks that field an `AJAX` function runs and deletes the row from the database table.

I am trying to figure out how to target that specific row in order to update the view to show the row has been deleted. I was either going to delete the whole row or change the color to red to show the user the row has been removed from the database.

**Question**

When a user clicks on a link inside a `<td>` of a dynamically creating table, how can I target the whole row in order to perform a DOM manipulating action on the row that was clicked?

**Example Code Table**

Notice the `onClick function` at the bottom. That function runs and when the AJAX function is successful I want to either remove the row or change the color of it.

```
    <tr>
      <th>Customer ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Download Letter</th>
      <th>Template ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $value->customer_id; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value->fname; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value->lname; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value->phone; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value->email; ?></td>
      <td><a href="<?php echo $value->pdf_file_path; ?>"><?php echo $value->template_heading; ?></a></td>
      <td><?php echo $value->temp_id; ?></td>
       <td>
            <a class="blue-text"><i class="options fa fa-user"></i></a>
            <a class="green-text"><i class="options fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            <a class="red-text" href="#" onClick="removePDF(user_id, customer_id, temp_id)"><i class="options fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**AJAX Function**

```
function removePDF(user_id, customer_id, temp_id){
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.example.com/script.php',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            user_email: user_email,
            user_id: user_id,
            customer_id: customer_id,
            temp_id: temp_id,
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `temp_id` is unique for each row?

Comment: no sire. email plus temp id make a url.

Comment: and one more thing is `tr` is being generated through any loop?

Comment: yes the whole table is in a for loop

Comment: but where is  user_id value define i am facing same issue it is says user_id not define

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As HTML is generated through script then you can have set some counter and add unique ID to every `<tr>` tag, and then pass that counter through `removePDF()` JS method.

Sample HTML code would be

```
<tr id="unique_num_<?= $unique_ctr; ?>">
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <td> 
        <a class="blue-text"><i class="options fa fa-user"></i></a>
        <a class="green-text"><i class="options fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <a class="red-text" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="removePDF(user_id, customer_id, temp_id, <?= $unique_ctr; ?>)"><i class="options fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Sample JS code will be

```
function removePDF(user_id, customer_id, temp_id, tr_num) {
    //...
    //...
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#unique_num_' + tr_num).remove();
        //or
        $('#unique_num_' + tr_num).addClass('my_class');
        //...
    }
    //...
    //...
}
```

Hope this helps!